# How to denote a non-exist element in empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X_1 = \emptyset$, and $X_2 = \{x\}$. If $X_1 = X_2$, then what should the element $x$ be? How to denote this $x$?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Green cheese. The empty set _cannot_ equal a singleton.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks very much! I agree with you that "something" is never equal to "nothing". Actually, the question I really want to ask is that is there any notation can denote "nothing"?

Comment: $1/\omega$, but i'm going with HM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation "$X_2=\{x\}$" implies that there is an element of $X_2$ - in particular, it requires that $X_2\not=\emptyset$. So the answer is that this situation cannot arise.

Comment: Thanks very much! I agree with you that "something" is never equal to "nothing". Actually, the question I really want to ask is that is there any notation can denote "nothing"?

Comment: @Ryan Sometimes the notation "$\uparrow$" is used to denote undefinedness - but usually when we mention an object, we require that it exist. We can write that no object exists with a certain property: $\forall x(\neg P(x))$; this, besides "$\uparrow$," is the closest I can think of to what you're asking.

Comment: I think this notation is what I really need, and many thinks again!